# selenium management tool

Tags: testing, scripting, selenium, automation

I am wondering what is the best management tool for SELENIUM. Something that handles automated running of tests with RC. Saves screenshots that selenium rc takes, connectivity to a database. What are some of the tools you guys use.

thank you

Comment: I'm afraid you may have mistaken the purpose of selenium. Thease are all things you would handle in your tests, using tops that are common in your language.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a [Continuous Integration](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html) server. It does everything that you want.